# Forgotten Google account password

Tags: google-account, password

I lost access to my account due to someone else getting into it. Google locked my account. When I finally got it back I was instructed to change my account password. Now I am trying to put my account on new phone and cannot remember my new password. How can I get or change my PW without going through google recovery, last time used recovery took 3 weeks to get my account back. Is there another way?

Comment: If there were another way, there wouldn't be much point in having a password at all. Could your web browser be remembering your password?

Answer (score -1):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/crackerpassword/?source=directory This might help you out some with cracking it . I cracked one on a computer i bought using this . Good Luck !!

Comment: Will it work on my cell?

Comment: No, it's only for reversing unsalted MD5 or SHA-1 hashes of passwords. You don't have either of those, so it's not relevant to your problem.